# JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet has stopped working

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, get

I am not sure why all of a sudden none of my AllowGet JsonRequests work. I have tried using a JsonBehaviorAttribute as well as setting the JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet in the return JsonResult call, and I still get a Request.Path error.

This was working for a long time and just seemed to stop. In Fiddler it traces to System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig and System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context).

Any reason this should suddenly stop working in MVC3?

Thanks for the help!
PK

Comment: What is the URL to the Action? It doesn't sound like JSON Request Behavior is the issue at all.

Comment: maybe you have some invalid characters in your url?
see the following http://www.christophercrooker.com/use-any-characters-you-want-in-your-urls-with-aspnet-4-and-iis

Comment: Good call from both of you. It turns out there was a "/" instead of the "?" that caused the problem. Thanks for answering!